# Frozen yogurt with inverted sugar

Tags: yogurt, frozen, frozen-yogurt

I wanna make frozen yogurt from homemade yogurt. I heard that inverted sugar can help prevent crystallization so I want to add it to my yogurt, because I don't want rock-hard frozen yogurt and I just want to use purely just yogurt and sweeteners, no gelatin, alcohol, cream or anything else added. I have some questions:

1. Should I add inverted sugar at the beginning before incubation? Or after, when my yogurt is firm?
2. Is it ok if I use homemade inverted sugar (the version made with sugar, water and lemon juice)? Should I replace all the amount of sugar by inverted sugar? I doubt that inverted sugar is sweeter than normal sugar and corn syrup (what I can't find in the supermarket where I live unfortunately).

Thank you very much for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you’re right, invert sugar slows down the crystal formation and improves the texture of frozen products.

The way I use invert sugar in most frozen products is as a direct substitutue for the added sugar; for the frozen yogurt, it is no exception. You can just follow your recipe and replace the sugar with invert sugar by 80% to 100% of the weight of the original amount of the sugar.

Since the bonds between the glucose and fructose are broken, invert sugar is sweeter. It's of course a matter of taste, but I don’t think you'll notice a very big difference, even if you replace it 1:1.